# Validar si existe un dato en la tabla haciendo uso de Entity Framework C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Tengo el siguiente código que me devuelve un boolean el cual me permite validar si ya existe o no en la tabla:

```
public bool Existencia_Historia_Clinica(String Id)
{
    string sql = @"SELECT COUNT(*)
                   FROM TBL_HISTORIA_CLINICA
                   WHERE HISCLI_COD_PAC = @HISCLI_COD_PAC AND 
                   HISCLI_EST_ELI!='F'";
    string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Trabajo"].ToString();

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
    {
         SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
         _ = command.Parameters.AddWithValue("HISCLI_COD_PAC", Id);
         conn.Open();

         int count = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());

         if (count == 0)
             return false;
         else
             return true;
    }
}
```

Como podria realizarlo haciendo uso de `Entity Framework`, de antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Debes publicar el nombre de los `DbSet` y las clases involucradas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

estimado @Japv tu respuesta me sirvió de mucho y si funciona en todos los aspectos, recibí otra recomendación que solo requiere de 3 líneas de código y es la que coloco para ayudar a los demás.

Como 1er paso creo la sgte función.

```
create function [dbo].[fn_Find_Historia_Clinica]
(@HISCLI_COD_PAC VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
return(
SELECT HISCLI_COD_PAC FROM TBL_HISTORIA_CLINICA 
WHERE HISCLI_COD_PAC = @HISCLI_COD_PAC AND HISCLI_EST_ELI!='F')
```

Como 2do paso haciendo uso de `Entity Framework` actualizo mi modelo para poder usarlo.

Y como 3er paso lo mando a llamar mediante código en donde utilizo la primera recomendación que me diste.

```
 public bool Existencia_Historia_Clinica(String HISCLI_COD_PAC)
    {
        DIENTES_SANOS_ENTITIES db = new DIENTES_SANOS_ENTITIES();
        var load_his = db.fn_Find_Historia_Clinica(HISCLI_COD_PAC);
        return load_his.Count() > 0;
    }
```

Validación al momento de llamar que verifica la existencia y tira el mensaje de error

```
 if (daoHisCli.Existencia_Historia_Clinica(CodPac) == true)
            {
                _ = MessageBox.Show("Registro Existente", "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                txtPac.Text = "";
                dataGridPaci.DataSource = daoPac.Cargar_Paciente_OdoCon(CodOdont);
                cmbProf.Select();

            }
            else if (daoHisCli.Existencia_Historia_Clinica(CodPac) == false)
            {
                Frm_Registrar_Historia_Clinica frm = new Frm_Registrar_Historia_Clinica
                {
                    Cod_Pac = CodPac,//Codigo del Paciente
                    Cod_Odont = txtId.Text, // Codigo del Odontologo
                    MdiParent = MdiParent //El Contenedor Hijo llama a otro formulario Hijo
                };
                frm.Show();
                Close();
            }
```

Comment: `return  (new DIENTES_SANOS_ENTITIES()).TBL_HISTORIA_CLINICA .Any(a=>a.HISCLI_COD_PAC == HISCLI_COD_PAC && a.HISCLI_EST_ELI != "F")` Ahí lo tienes en una línea de código, sin necesitar funciones SQL y más eficiente y rápida que las 2 soluciones presentadas.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar **Linq**:

**Variante 1**:

```
int total = dbContext.tblHistoriaClinica.Count(t => t.id == id);

if(total > 0)
{
    //Duplicado
}
else
{
    //Tu código
}
```

Aquí usas el **operador Count** para contar los elementos cuyo **id** es igual al **id** por el que deseas comparar, en caso de que exista al menos una coincidencia ese elemento está duplicado.

**Variante 2**:

```
var x = dbContext.tblHistoriaClinica.FirstOrDefault(t => t.id == id);

if(x != null)
{
    //Duplicado
}
else
{
    //Tu código
}
```

Usas el **operador FirstOrDefault**, el cual devuelve el primer elemento que cumple con la condición de coincidencia, si el resultado devuelto no es nulo indica que está duplicado, caso contrario no lo está. También puedes usar los **operadores First**, **LastOrDefault** y **Last**.

**Variante 3**:

```
var x = dbContext.Where(t => t.id == id).Count();

if(x > 0)
{
    //Duplicado
}
else
{
    //Tu código
}
```

Aquí se usa el **operador Where** para filtrar por la condición dada, y una vez hecho el filtro, se aplica el **operador Count** para contar el total de elementos que se filtraron. Si ese total da mayor que **0** entonces hay duplicados, caso contrario no los hay.

**Variante 4**:

```
bool duplicado = false;

foreach( var t in dbContext.tblHistoriaClinica)
{
    if(t.id == id)
    {
        duplicado = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(duplicado == false)
{
    //Tu código
}
```

Aquí usas un **ciclo foreach**, para recorrer cada elemento de la colección y por cada elemento preguntas si se cumple la condición, en caso de cumplirse, se le da el **valor** **true** a la **variable duplicado** y se termina el ciclo. Esto también lo puedes hacer con un **ciclo for**, un **ciclo while**, o con un **do while**, también podrías aplicar el **método GetEnumerator** a la colección y hacer tú mismo la iteración con el **método MoveNext** hasta que se cumpla la condición o se termine el ciclo.

**Nota 1**: Para usar **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```

**Nota 2**: Asumo que ya tienes tu modelo lógico hecho en **EntityFramework** y que tu contexto se llama **dbContext**.

**Nota 3**: Mi respuesta es genérica, te toca a ti poner las condiciones correctas para hallar duplicados, analiza está respuesta y adaptala a tus necesidades.

Ah y por cierto también puedes usar el **operador Any**, casi se me olvidaba.

Comment: Siempre hay alguien que se esconde en el anonimato para votar negativamente una respuesta correcta, al menos dime qué supones tu q tengo mal

Comment: Yo te he votado negativamente, lo hice por 2 motivos: (1) Tu respuesta es inexacta, pones `t.id == id`, cual id?? El código del usuario muestra 2 campos dentro del `Where` y tu uno, ninguno de ellos se llama `id`. (2)  Count se usa para contar, recorre toda la lista y cuenta cuantos elementos cumple la condición. Lo correcto sería ocupar `Any` que detiene la búsqueda cuando encuentra el primero que cumple la condición.

Comment: @Yussef me imaginé que fuiste tú, primero me diste tu voto porque te dio la gana, mi respuesta no es inexacta, le toca al op entenderla y adaptarla a su problema, segundo usar un Count en vez de un Any no es motivo para votarle negativo a nadie, use el Count, también pude usar un Any, un Where, un First, un sin fin de variantes, mejor dime qué fue porque te dio la gana, ya que ese fue el motivo de tu voto.

Comment: @Yussef por otra parte los usuarios que tienen cierta cantidad de puntos como tú y yo deben respetarse, lo correcto hubiera sido que me avisaras de esos errores, para corregirlos, no actuar como lo hiciste que yo no empecé ayer en la comunidad ni tengo 3 puntos, se trata de respeto

Comment: No es porque me dio la gana, fíjate que he respondido tu comentario rápidamente porque al votarte he puesto en seguimiento tu respuesta para ver si la editabas y así retirar mi voto. Pero es que gano yo al votarte negativo??? es que no tiene sentido lo que me estás imputando. El `count` es para contar y el `Any` es para evaluar si existe alguno. Para mí eso ya es motivo suficiente para votar negativamente, y también considero que una buena respuesta debe centrarse en el problema específico.

Comment: No entiendo porque crees que no te respeto, creo que nuevamente te sales de tema y haces juicios de valor que no corresponden. No tengo porque comentar los votos que hago, ni si tienen 100k de pts ni si tienen 1pt, para mí eso es irrelevante. Y si lo he hecho ahora fue porque lo pediste y yo gentilmente te expliqué mis motivos. Que podría no haberlo hecho y haber seguido con mi vida. Y te insisto fíjate que dejé la respuesta en seguimiento, para cambiar el voto a penas editaras la pregunta. Cuantos más hacen lo mismo?

Comment: @Yussef evidentemente tú ni entiendes ni duermes, aki donde yo vivo ya es de madrugada, yo mi respuesta la puedo arreglar perfectamente mañana, y tanto el Count como el Any sirven para detectar duplicados de hecho, hay situaciones donde el Count suele ser más eficiente

Comment: No sé qué pensar de tu comentario, francamente no tiene sentido. No duermo? que tiene que ver eso? --  no entiendo? que debo entender, eres tú el que me pidió explicaciones a mí, es decir tu eres el que debe entender no yo -- Tu respuesta puedes arreglarla cuando gustes, y yo te dije que cuando la arreglaras retiraba el voto, cual es el problema? -- Puede ser que hayan situaciones donde el Count sea mejor, este no es el caso

Comment: @Yussef mi respuesta se queda como está, en todo caso la eliminaría, respecto a mí comentario piensa lo que quieras me da lo mismo, lo único q no tiene sentido es tu accionar,  lo correcto hubiera sido que me avisaras de esos supuestos errores, antes de votarme y esperar a que yo los arreglarse cuando pudiera, en caso de considerar que tus aclaraciones fueran correctas, el voto negativo debe ser siempre la última opción no la primera, aprendete eso, y no votes más por votar, voy a dormir